# modifying derived class values from base class

Tags: c#, reflection, derived-class, base-class

Is it possible to have a method in a base class to modify a derived class' properties? I was thinking something like this:

```
public class baseclass
{
  public void changeProperties(string propertyName, string newValue)
  {
    try
    {
      this.propertyName = newValue;
    }
    catch
    {
      throw new NullReferenceException("Property doesn't exist!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems a code smell to me. I'd prefer a virtual method in the base class to make the modification. It could be empty in the base class, and overloaded in any derived classes that need it.

Comment: if you're doing something like `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation, this is pretty common.  Instead of the propertyName, you pass the property to the method by reference.  Though on second look, You are actually trying to rewrite the property's name.  You can't/don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem via reflection, because `this` reference's type will be equal actual type, i.e. type of derived class:

**[Solution:](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BQLWhU)**

```
public class baseclass
{
    public void changeProperties(string propertyName, object newValue)
    {            
        var prop = GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        if (prop == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("Property doesn't exist!");
        else
            prop.SetValue(this, newValue);
    }
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
public class Test : baseclass
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new Test();
        test.changeProperties("Age", 2);
    }
}
```